# Decryption returns an empty string when encrypting text in Android

Tags: java, android, encryption, android-security

I'm trying to save few text fields securely. For that I'm trying to encrypt and decrypt the content. This is the code:

```
public class SecureStorage {

    public String getPassword() {
        if(!isRooted()) {
            String password = pref.getPassword("");
            System.out.println("pass getPass: " + password);
            return password.isEmpty() ? password : new String(decrypt(Base64.decode(password, Base64.DEFAULT)));

        } else
            return "";
    }

    public void setPassword(String passwordStr) {
        if(!isRooted()) {
            byte[] password = encrypt(passwordStr.getBytes());
            pref.setPassword(password == null ? "" : Base64.encodeToString(password, Base64.DEFAULT));
        }
    }

    private SecretKey generateKey() {
        // Generate a 256-bit key
        final int outputKeyLength = 256;
        try {
            SecureRandom secureRandom = new SecureRandom();
            // Do *not* seed secureRandom! Automatically seeded from system entropy.
            KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
            keyGenerator.init(outputKeyLength, secureRandom);
            return keyGenerator.generateKey();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    private byte[] getRawKey(byte[] key) throws Exception {
        KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
        SecureRandom secureRandom = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG", "Crypto");
        secureRandom.setSeed(key);
        keyGenerator.init(128, secureRandom); // 192 and 256 bits may not be available
        SecretKey secretKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
        byte[] rawKey = secretKey.getEncoded();
        return rawKey;
    }

    /** The method that encrypts the string.
     @param toEncrypt The string to be encrypted.
     @return The encrypted string in bytes. */
    //****************************************
    private byte[] encrypt(byte[] toEncrypt) {
        byte[] encryptedByte = new String().getBytes();
        try {
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(getRawKey(Utils.generateUID().getBytes()), "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
            encryptedByte = cipher.doFinal(toEncrypt);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return encryptedByte;
    }

    //**************************************
    /** The method that decrypts the string.
     @param encryptedByte The string to be encrypted.
     @return The decrypted string in bytes. */
    //****************************************
    private byte[] decrypt(byte[] encryptedByte) {
        byte[] decryptedByte = new String().getBytes();
        try {
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(getRawKey(Utils.generateUID().getBytes()), "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
            decryptedByte = cipher.doFinal(encryptedByte);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return decryptedByte;
    }
}
```

I'm able to encrypt the Text. 
I'm using SharedPreferences to store the encrypted text and getting the sharedprefs to decrypt the text and give it to a TextView. But in the `getPassword()` I'm getting the SharedPreference value and trying to decrypt if there is any value in the SharedPrefs. I'm getting the SharedPrefs into a string (`password`) and trying to decrypt it, but I'm unable to! I'm getting an empty String!

Comment: what is `pref.getPassword("");` doing ?

Comment: You're getting an empty string, because you're catching all possible exception cases. Have you looked into your logs to see which exception is thrown? I suspect it's a BadPaddingException

Comment: got it!, Im generation a random key and not saving it! So now when im calling back a new key. Now im saving the key also along with the Text!

Answer (score 1):

CBC mode needs an initialization vector (IV) in order to operate. The IV is there to randomize the ciphertext and prevent an attacker from determining whether previous plaintexts had the same prefix as the current one.

Since you're not generating any IV, it will be generated for you. A wrong IV only affects the first block (first 16 bytes for AES). If your plaintext is shorter than a block, then this will lead to completely different decryption and then the padding cannot be removed with a probability of roughly 255/256.

The IV is not supposed to be secret. It is common to prepend it to the ciphertext and slice it off before decryption.

```
public byte[] encrypt(byte[] toEncrypt) throws Exception {
    try {
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(getRawKey(Utils.generateUID().getBytes()), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
        byte[] iv = cipher.getIV();
        byte[] ct = cipher.doFinal(toEncrypt);

        byte[] result = new byte[ct.length + iv.length];
        System.arraycopy(iv, 0, result, 0, iv.length);
        System.arraycopy(ct, 0, result, iv.length, ct.length);
        return result;
    } catch(...) {...}
    return new byte[0];
}

public byte[] decrypt(byte[] encryptedByte) throws Exception {
    try {
        SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(getRawKey(Utils.generateUID().getBytes()), "AES");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        byte[] iv = new byte[cipher.getBlockSize()];
        byte[] ct = new byte[encryptedByte.length - cipher.getBlockSize()];
        System.arraycopy(encryptedByte, 0, iv, 0, cipher.getBlockSize());
        System.arraycopy(encryptedByte, cipher.getBlockSize(), ct, 0, ct.length);

        cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
        return cipher.doFinal(ct);
    } catch (...) {...}
    return new byte[0];
}
```

The problem with this might be that the ciphertext is bigger than anticipated (16 bytes additionally for the IV). If you can make sure that an attacker doesn't get any useful information from determining that previous plaintexts had the same prefix, then you could use a static IV. But be aware that this is usually not that great of an idea and should only be done if you *really need* that space.

```
private static final byte[] IV = new byte[16];
...
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(IV));
cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(IV));
```